Full qualified names for DOM's FIle interface and Node.js's File interface
From v18, Node.js the experimental File interface has been added. It could conflict with DOM's File interface in full-stack projects.
Currently, the TypeScript correctly understand which File means, but the ESLint could complain:
try {

  // ESLint: The 'File' is still an experimental feature and is not supported until Node. js 20.0.0. 
  // The configured version range is '>=16.0.0'
  newBase64EncodedFiles = await Promise.all(
    newFiles.map(async (file: File): Promise<string> => encodeFileToBase64(file))
  );

} catch (error: unknown) {

  // ...
  
}

Besides persuading of ESLint, for the code readability it's better to specify the full qualified name like NodeJS.File and Window.File. However, there is not Window namespace.
